# Run Android Emulators from windows in a Hyper-V virtual machine

Tags: android, windows, android-emulator, virtual-machine, visual-studio-2022

The Set Up

I have a personal (gaming) Windows 10 Pro PC and I want to use it for some home development work without loading up the gaming side with extra installs.  Win10 Pro allows you to create virtual machines using Hyper-V and the Hyper-V Manager.

I used the quick start to create a Win11 Dev environment.  When I logged in I downloaded and installed Visual Studio 2022 community, and Myql Workbench.  I have a MySql Server on a separate box on my network and the Win11 VM can connect to it.

There is a program I wrote using VS2022 and Ximiran to learn Mobile App development and thar is what I want to work on again.  It was written on a regular Dev box where I could launch android emulators and/or connect my mobile device to test.

I tried setting up the Android ADM with the standard emulator (Pixel 5 API 30), a more generic 6.7dpi (API 32) and while I was able to DL and install them, they failed.

The Issue

I did read many google and SO entries and I saw that the emulators would not work in Virtual Box, but I did not see anything with hyper-v.  I did changes the windows features to use hyper-v, windows hypervisor, and set up the SDK > tools > Extras > intel x86 ... (HAXM accelerator).

When I start either emulator I get an error then when boiled down says "ERROR | x86-64 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration." ... "Android Emulator requires an intel processor with VT-x and NX support.  (VT-x is not supported).

The Question

Is this just a situation where no matter what I try this combination of a PC running a VM running an Emulator will just not work?

If it can, what piece am I missing?

The VM knows I have a Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4970K CPU @ 4.00GHz and this is a 64bit OS.  This  also has a GeForce RTX 3060 gpu which the VM does not see.

Any thoughts would be welcomed.  I would like to keep my two environments separate and though I can code almost anything else, I would like to work on my android app in VS2022.

(I may try plugging in my mobile device...hmmmm)